# Azure DevOps : Process Rules : 'Clear the value of' action not working

Tags: azure-devops

Created several rules using 'clear the value of ' as action, but none of them are working. In the first rule that I created, Condition : When no value is defined for Related Link Count then action : Clear the value of title.

Second rule, Condition : When no value is defined for description, Action : Clear the value of Assigned to.

None of the above seem to work. I tried several other permutations and combinations with 'clear the value of' but none seem to work.

Comment: For your second rules, you can try with add description and assigned account at same time, and save it. Then, delete  description content, you will see that the account assigned be cleared. Could you update your operation, after you set the rules?

Comment: Second rule seems to work now, however the first one does not.

Comment: For your first rule, does Related Work Count is Related Link Count?

Comment: Yes, corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second rule, it doesn't work may caused by your operation. You should add description and assigned first. And then, delete the description content, you will see that the account assigned be cleared.

But, for first rule. As I checked, I found that no matter what the action is, while the condition is related to `Related Link Count`, the rule will all be abnormal-- could not be applied normally.

For this error, you can report this problem [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21). Our engineer can investigate this issue and will fix it.